# WCF issue while updating from 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I recently upgraded my VS solution and projects from 3.5 to 4.0 framework. After conversion I am facing a problem when sending entity objects to WCF. When I send an entity which has no other child entities or any relation with other entities, everything works fine... the data is passed to WCF. But when the entity has a child entity I get the following error when calling my WCF service method:

> The EntityReference object could not be serialized. This type of object cannot be 
>     serialized when the RelationshipManager belongs to an entity object that does not 
>     implement IEntityWithRelationships.

Any idea what's gone wrong? I wasn't facing any issues when using framework 3.5.

Comment: To be clear, you're passing the whole EF generated class (3.5-style, not a POCO) over WCF including the extra `-Field` properties and the `EntityKey` and `EntityState` properties? You probably want something lighter-weight for data transfer. Not sure if that's directly related to this error, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this post on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/adonetefx/thread/60BBFF42-DBBC-4B7C-9A2F-B4A78D4B5FEC) will be useful?